# My German National Work Visa Got Rejected due to Submitted Provisional Master Degree Certificate

Tags: germany, visa

Recently I have received heartbreaking news from German Consulate Bangalore stating that "The Bachelor degree submitted is not registered as recognised degree in Germany. The Master degree is only provisional. We need the final degree. Thus one of the requirements for a Blue Card EU was not meet and visa could not be granted".

I have recently completed my Master Degree and here in India firstly University Provide Official Transcript (Final Degree Grade Card) along with Provisional Pass certificate and thereafter exactly one year the convocation will take place and Final Degree Certificate will be handed over to students. So I have submitted the Provisional Certificate along with Official Transcript but The Visa Officer is not kept the Official Transcript and as a result, I got rejection. So please if anyone familiar with this situation kindly suggest to me.

Comment: So it appears you have **two** issues : 1. The Masters is provisional and 2. The Bachelor degree is not recognized. You may need to find a solution to both issues, not just one...

Comment: @GittingGud actually this fits expatriates.stackexchange.com/ better.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on Expatriates SE.

Comment: Hi Gopal. Since this is about visas and not work, please ask at our site specially for visas and working abroad: [expatriates.se].

Answer (score 3):

from https://www.eu-bluecard.com/validity/

> You have the right to appeal for re-evaluation of your EU Blue Card permit status. The hosting states’ competent authorities will determine the court and the time where the appeal may take place. If you do not apply before the deadline, you will be rejected.

So you should have the right to appeal the Blue Card Visa rejection decision within a limited time frame.

However, your rejection appears to have been based on the grounds that a provisional confirmation of a qualifying document is inadequate - only the actual document will be accepted.

If you appeal and submit the same documents it's highly unlikely the decision will be any different this time. Several rejections could also be held against you when reapplying later.

You should wait until you received the document required before reapplying.

Comment: OP thinks the transcript, which was an official and final document, wasn't given proper consideration.  Maybe that meets the requirement, maybe only a diploma does.  But it's not clear that resubmitting would be doomed to the same failure.  It might even be advantageous to submit the final transcript and leave the provisional diploma out of the review.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, in order to get a Blue Card in Germany you MUST have a bachelor degree where both the degree and institution where you got it are listed in the [ANABIN Database](https://anabin.kmk.org/anabin.html).

In case it doesn't, I see two options:

1 - You can try to get you degree validated through the [ZAB](https://www.kmk.org/zab/zentralstelle-fuer-auslaendisches-bildungswesen.html). Takes a few weeks, requires a few documents and you have to pay. But if everything goes OK, you can then try to get the Blue Card

2 - You can forget the Blue Card and try to get the Work Visa (also known as Specialist Visa) which is described [here](https://www.germany-visa.org/work-employment-visa/). It has a few differences when compared with the Blue Card, but nothing to worry about. Also, it doesn't required that you have a bachelor's degree (or any degree at all, for that matter). The only real downside is that your employer will have to try to get the approval for your hiring from the [ZAV](https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/vor-ort/zav/startseite), which may or may not be troublesome, depending on how specialized your profession is. If you get the ZAV's approval, you just print the document that they will send your employer and take it, along with the other documents, to the consulate/embassy where you are getting the visa.